# VT - Hyper V - Window 10 family

Tags: window, virtual, hyper-v

I have just bought my new computer in a Windows 10 upgraded from Windows 7.

However I can't run the virtual android application from Android studio.

I have been in the appdata, and it says virtual tech if not enable, hence I have been in the bios, but it says it does.

Now I am looking for HYPER-V, cause it is apparently mutually exclusive, however it is not in the cmm...

Any idea how can I have my virtual device with the android studio? It really locks me out in my work development.

Thank you.

Comment: C:\Users\fnacgp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Galaxy_Nexus_API_22 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Comment: This computer meets the requirement for HAXM, but intel virtualization tech VT-x is not turn on etc...